# Dating photo of car and camper from about 1940s?

Tags: 20th-century, photo-identification, michigan

I have this family photo:

[image]

showing a camping trip at McCullens Lake, Michigan, United States for Robert Carroll and his wife Mag.

I'd like to estimate the date it was taken from the car and the camper.  I'm guessing it looks around 1940.

Comment: What's on the flip side of the print?  Sometimes there are codes/marks from the processor or supplier.

Comment: I don't have access to photo at moment, so only have front side.

Comment: Best *guess* is that's a Buick or Oldsmobile, 1940's vintage.  The camper is a "Kill it with fire!" and really makes one re-appreciate those old Wally Byam models. ;)

Comment: @Brock I think your comment is enough to place into a brief answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo, if you want to incorporate something into an answer go ahead.  I don't want to do the referencing, right now, necessary to support my statements above. (But the "Kill it with fire!" is self-evident.)

Comment: I would say the car is more like a 1935 model , which would be in common use in 1940.

Comment: @blacksmith37, could be anywhere in about a 15 year span.  If you figure out what model it is, please comment-reply to me. (I know I saw a coupe with those kinds of features, a few decades back, and it's annoying that I can't place it.)